# Unable to get a database array to display in an alert window?

Tags: javascript, arrays, alert

This is a SCHOOL PROJECT! I am only a few weeks into learning JavaScript - I am trying my best and trying to learn this but really need help, so again I'm reaching out to those who are well versed and knowledgeable for some assistance...

No code errors coming up and unsure why this won't display in an ALERT window on the "admin" page of this project. Any thoughts or ideas would be greatly appreciated! Thanks...

Here is the JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/qux3K/1/

And here is the code:

```
// Chapters 7 & 8 - store.js
```

// This script creates a "fake" database that stores the available CD's in our music store collection.

```
// Function called when page is loaded.
// Function creates a new object.
function process() {
'use strict';


// Create a new array:
var cd = new Array ([
    {"cd":0, "item":"001", "title": "Total Life Forever", "artist": "FOALS",         "price": "$14.99", "released": "March, 2009", "tracks": "Track Listing"     {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}, "quantity": "1"}
    {"cd":1, "item":"002", "title": "Bein Love", "artist": "Locksley", "price": "$14.99", "released": "April, 2012", "tracks": "Track Listing" {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}, "quantity": "1"}
    {"cd":2, "item":"003", "title": "Privileged", "artist": "Nick Moss", "price": "$14.99", "released": "June, 2011", "tracks": "Track Listing" {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}, "quantity": "1"}
    {"cd":3, "item":"004", "title": "Asondeguerra", "artist": "Juan Louis Guerra", "price": "$14.99", "released": "September, 2013", "tracks": "Track Listing" {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}, "quantity": "1"}
    {"cd":4, "item":"017", "title": "Way Out Here", "artist": "Josh Thompson", "price": "$14.99", "released": "August, 2010", "tracks": "Track Listing" {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}, "quantity": "1"}
    {"cd":5, "item":"018", "title": "Tremolo", "artist": "The Pines", "price": "$14.99", "released": "January, 2007", "tracks": "Track Listing" {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}, "quantity": "1"}
    {"cd":6, "item":"019", "title": "Live From Freedom Hall", "artist": "Lynyrd Skynyrd", "price": "$14.99", "released": "June, 2010", "tracks": "Track Listing" {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}, "quantity": "1"}
    {"cd":7, "item":"020", "title": "Achin' & Shakin'", "artist": "Laura Bell Bundy", "price": "$14.99", "released": "July, 2013", "tracks": "Track Listing" {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}, "quantity": "1"}
    {"cd":8, "item":"021", "title": "Here I Am", "artist": "Marvin Sapp", "price": "$14.99", "released": "November, 2011", "tracks": "Track Listing" {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}, "quantity": "1"}
    {"cd":9, "item":"022", "title": "Just James", "artist": "J Moss", "price": "$14.99", "released": "March, 2011", "tracks": "Track Listing" {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}, "quantity": "1"}
    {"cd":10, "item":"013", "title": "Tom Petty - Live", "artist": "Tom Petty", "price": "$14.99", "released": "May, 2010", "tracks": "Track Listing" {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}, "quantity": "1"}
]); 


// Function to call titles in an alert box
alert('CD titles available are' + cd({title:"0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10"}));
// End of alert.    


} 
// End of process() function.

// Initial setup:
function init() {
'use strict';
document.getElementById('theForm').onsubmit = process;

} // End of init() function.
window.onload = init;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several errors.

If you are using Array constructor as

```
var cd = new Array ([...]);
```

you actually defined array of array of object. You have to use just

```
var cd = new Array(...)
```

or just

```
var cd = [...];
```

Each array item, which is object in you case, needs ',' after it like

```
var cd = new Array(1, 2, 3)
```

In your case:

```
var cd = new Array({...}, {...}, {...});
```

There is an object property

```
"tracks": "Track Listing"     {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12},
```

Here you put after ":" string and object {1, 2...}. What you wanted to define?

```
"tracks": {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12},
```

or something else?

And you get each title using for example, for loop

```
for (var i = 0; i < cd.length; i++)
    alert("CD Title: " + cd[i].title);
```

Comment: thanks for the information. I'm trying the corrections as you pointed out but still unable to get it work properly. It's pretty difficult to apply what I see in videos and read that seems to make sense until I'm trying to write it myself! Aaarrgggghhhh......

Comment: Start small. One array item with one object with one property and get that working. And then expand. For example `var cd = new Array ({"cd":0, "item":"001"});` and get cd or item displayed.

Comment: Thanks, Anto. Got it to work within the HTML, still trying to get it working with the JS code in an external file, just can't seem to figure that out. I appreciate your help...

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
var cd = new Array ([
    {"cd":0, "item":"001", "title": "Total Life Forever", "artist": "FOALS",             "price": "$14.99", "released": "March, 2009", "tracks": "Track Listing"     {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}, "quantity": "1"},
    // ...
]);
```

just write

```
var cd = [
    {...},
    {...},
];
```

And `cd({...})` won't work, since cd is an Array and not a function.

You will (have to) learn quite a lot in school ;-)

Comment: made the changes but still doesn't open the alert window, thank you though. And yes, I know I have a lot to learn but didn't everyone when they started?? What matters most is that I'm sincerely trying...

Comment: I didn't want do insult you. It's good that you learn JavaScript und we like to help you since you're trying hard. Have fun, you'll master it!

Comment: I wasn't insulted by your remarks and you have nothing to apologize for! There are others on this site that are very arrogant, condescending, and rude - you're not one of them. Thank you...